# compare two sql table and show which columns are different

Tags: mysql, sql, except

I already have the following query which show me the difference between two tables, what I need to find out is that which columns are different , is there any way

```
select * from [10.150.31.22].[database_a].[dbo].[table_a]
except
select * from [10.143.31.29].[database_b].[dbo].[table_b]
```

I need something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7R0S.jpg)

Comment: that looks more like SQL SERVER, but even then you need to add much more information

Comment: Sample data, desired results, an explanation of what you mean by "different", and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.Id, COALESCE(A.Name,-1), COALESCE(A.Age,-1), COALESCE(B.Name,-1), COALESCE(B.Age,-1)
FROM [10.150.31.22].[database_a].[dbo].[table_a] AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN [10.143.31.29].[database_b].[dbo].[table_b] AS B
ON A.Id = B.Id
WHERE COALESCE(A.Name,-1) <> COALESCE(A.Age,-1) OR COALESCE(B.Name,-1) <> COALESCE(B.Age,-1);
```

Comment: Assumes name and age are never NULL.  Considering you use an outer join, that's a bad assumption.  Also, doesn't cope with rows that exist in B but not in A.